# Product not listed in search results if in multiple categories

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

If I assign a product in 2 categories, for example `Roses->English Roses` that product will no longer appear in search results (either quick search or advanced search)

If I put it in just one category, either `Roses` OR `English Roses` the search works as expected.

What might affect this?

I tried the usual suspects like reindexing, caches, the inventory management is disabled from config, all products are enabled...

The problem appeared after the shop administrator moved products from one category to the other, reorganized some categories, etc.

Comment: What is your search string? have you customized the search?

Comment: I have made no customizations to search. Example keyword: "constance", the exact title for a product. I'm tempted to install a fresh magento to see if this is reproducible.

Comment: Try with a vanilla Magento + sample db ... I tested on mine (Magento 1.7.0.2) and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was "fixed" by disabling and re-enabling the products.